# uninitialized constant Mercury

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mercury-editor

I can't get Mercury set up.

I did the steps in the ReadMe, installed the gem and generated the Mercury assets.

Nothing happens when I access the `/editor` path though, and, when I run `rake routes`, I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Mercury
```

I'm on Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3, running on a Mongoid server.

Did I overlook something obvious or is it an error in the gem?

Comment: did you run bundle after installing? how did you install it? is it required in your gemfile?

Comment: I most definitely did. What is the usual reason that "uninitialized constant" error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make it work. Not totally sure why it worked though:

Seems like I have to require mercury in my application.rb:

```
require 'mercury/rails'
```

Do you think this is how it should be done or is my mercury gem acting funny?

Comment: It is as if there is a `require: false` following the gem name in the Gemfile.  Is this the case?